# Context not being set with apache maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I tried this, http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html#Using_a_different_context_path, but instead of having the application deployed under /my/custom/context/3.1 context, it was deployed under the artifactId-version context.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/my/custom/context/3.1</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any clue what could be the problem?

Comment: Define "without any luck" please. What happened when you tried it, what did you expect, etc.

Comment: Had you previously deployed the application under the `${artifactId-version}` context?

Comment: Try looking in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` for a context XML file that corresponds to the old application name, and deleting it. This can also be accomplished by using the `undeploy` goal of the tomcat7-maven-plugin.

Comment: There's no such file there. Here's my server.xml configuration. http://fpaste.org/173572/23762142/